# How can I print a label in ZPL203 in Delphi10

Tags: delphi, printing, zebra-printers

I have a label in ZPL203-Format. Does anyone know how I can print this with Delphi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have printed the label to a file on disk (mylabel.prn), you can copy it programmatically to the network share name, just as if you copy it manually with

```
copy mylabel.prn \\server\printername
```

by reading its content into a memory stream and then writing the stream to a file (using a TFileStream).